# Partition history SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-partitioning

I'm using SQL Server 2014, is there any possible way to see the history of the partition?

Somehow the partition schema changed and i would like to know how did it happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema changes get logged to the default trace and should appear in the **Schema Changes History** report (as long as it is enabled and hasn't rolled over in the meantime).

To view this report in SSMS, right click the database in consideration and choose

```
Reports -> Standard Reports -> Schema Changes History
```

To do the same with **TSQL**,

```
SELECT StartTime
       ,LoginName
       --,f.*
FROM   sys.traces t
       CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.path),
                                                       CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(t.path)), 
                                                       260)
                                             ) + N'log.trc', DEFAULT) f
WHERE  t.is_default = 1
       AND ObjectName = 'FOO'
       AND EventClass IN (46, /*Object:Created*/
                          47, /*Object:Dropped*/
                          164 /*Object:Altered*/ )
```

For more information refer - [Schema Changes History Report](https://sqlandme.com/2011/07/14/sql-server-management-studio-schema-changes-history-report/)